# Apply shipping without the shipping screen

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Folks:

All the products in the store I am working have only one shipping method (ground). It seems redundant to have people go through the shipping screen since there is only one shipping option. Is there a way to just apply the default shipping for the product(s) based on the address they enter rather than going through the shipping screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can automatically set the shipping method on a cart (e.g. by an ajax call) at any point by POSTing to `commerce/cart/updateCart` - You just use an input with name `shippingMethod` and and the value you supply is the handle of your shipping method, e.g. `ground'.

Where you do this is entirely up to you, but note depending how you handle/implement this, changes in the cart contents & addresses can invalidate shipping methods, so you'd typically do this at some point after your cart index page...

Comment: Do you have an example for this? I have tried to add to add the input to the address form but it then breaks, stating that the amount does not add up although shipping has no cost.

Comment: Got it working. Shipping methods weren’t enabled on the front end.

Comment: @MarcusScheller Can you post an example of your solution here?

Comment: @KSPR I just enabled the shipping methods.